# SQL Server - I want to select database based on an identifier used

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, identifier, multiple-databases

I have multiple databases. Can I hit one of the databases based on an identifier which is dynamic?
e.g. I have three databases `DB1,DB2,DB3`.

I have a query `select * from tblEmployees`.(This table is present in all the three DBs). I have an identifier(or some variable ) whose value can be 1 or 2 or 3 and based on the value of this variable which I get dynamically when my service is hit, I would like to choose the DB from which the values should be obtained.

Can this be done? My DB is `SQL Server` and front end is `asp.net`.

My connection strings are stored in web.config file. Can I have multiple connection string which will have the same server with diff db names and select one of  them based on the identifier.

Comment: You have to create the connection string dynamically each time.

Comment: try with this exec('select * from ' + @identifier +'.tblEmployees')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.In real world most of the time you have to store your connection strings in your web.config file .
so there you can let's keep three connection strings which will have the same server but different databases name, then you can select one of the connection-string for your app connection to the required database.

2.you can build that connection string on run-time if you need.

using these technique you will never have to write 2 or more queries just change the query string and your queries will work for all the databases.

Comment: This is quite close to my answer. I would be so glad if you can please give me any example.

Comment: Done. I have added multiple connection strings. Now how do I select one of them based on my requirement dynamically?

Comment: string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStringName"];

Comment: <appSettings>
    <!-- None, Db, Resource -->
    <add key="Connectionstring name" value="Connectionstring"/>
  </appSettings>

Comment: AppSettings is not a must it may be in some another tag in web.config. get it Accordingly in c#.

Comment: Thanks so much khalid. This gives me insights I needed. Will solve my problems (hopefully). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
if(val == 1)
{
  select * from [DB1].[dbo].[tblEmployees]
}
else if(val == 2)
{
  select * from [DB2].[dbo].[tblEmployees]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. I actually have a stored procedure in two different DBs. I want to call the proc based on this value. Can this be done?

Comment: you have to modify your connection string accordingly for this if you wanna do this in c#

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @ID INT
SELECT @ID = 2

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM DB' + CAST(@ID AS CHAR(1)) + '.dbo.tblEmployees'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output -

```
SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.tblEmployees
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL way:

```
declare @db int


if @db = 1
begin

    use [db1]
    select *
    from tblEmployees

end

if @db = 2
begin
    use [db2]
    select *
    from tblEmployees
end

-- and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you're best bet would be to use a different connection-string to achieve multi-tenency against similar alike databases. Ideally, abstracted away behind some code so that most of your code *doesn't need to know about it*, but just does:

```
using(var conn = Somewhere.GetOpenConnection()) {
    // ...
}
```

or worst-case:

```
using(var conn = Somewhere.GetOpenConnection(Environment.Published)) {
    // ...
}
```

(here `Environment` is an `enum` to what the various databases represent)

where `GetOpenConnection` figures out which database is needed, and either looks up on constructs the correct connection string.

But to be specific:

- you cannot parameterize the DB name in a query
- using `use` between operations would be a really bad idea in terms of connection re-use
- you can explicitly use three-part identifiers (i.e. `DB1..SomeTable` or `DB1.dbo.SomeTable`), but that does not scale naturally to lots of databases